# Dynamically add dropdownlists to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I'm trying to add multiple dropdownlists to a table from the code behind.
The problem I'm having is that when I try to fill the dropdownlists it goes wrong.

The first dropdownlist gets the values like it's supposed to; the second one gets filled with the values of the first one and its own values.

```
protected void Page_Init()
{
    string product = Request.QueryString["product"];
    foreach (productoption r in dbcon.GetOption(product))
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cel1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cel2 = new TableCell();
        DropDownList dropdown1 = new DropDownList();
        dropdown1.ID = Convert.ToString(r.ProductOptionID);
        foreach (suboption f in dbcon.GetSubOption(r.ProductOptionID))
        {
            dropdown1.Items.Add(f.SubOptionName + " +$" +f.SubOptionPrice);
        }
        cel1.Text = r.OptionName;
        cel2.Controls.Add(dropdown1);
        row.Cells.Add(cel1);
        row.Cells.Add(cel2);
        Table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

I tried to add `dropdown1.Items.Clear()` and `dropdown1.ClearSelection()` but that didn't work

Comment: Have you checked that `dbcon.GetSubOption(r.ProductOptionID)` returns only the supposed items?

Comment: yeah the first time it returns 2 values and the second time 1 value however the second dropdownlist gets 3 values

Comment: is this a simplified example? I have no access to VS right now to check, but judging from your code I would say the described behavior should not occur

Comment: Damn I just found what's wrong.. I needed to clear the list in the database class that was returned